# Providing complex filtering REST API

Tags: api, rest

So I am building a RESTful (as RESTful as I can) API with the Laravel 4 PHP Framework.  Right now I have dozens of API calls working and I have a process for being to do limit, ordering, and do simple filtering.  Here would be an example of one of the calls:

```
/api/v1/users?limit=10&offset=10&firstName=John&order[]=createdTimestamp desc
```

This would return the 11th through 20th users that have a first name of John ordered by the createdTimestamp in descending order.  The simple filtering here can only does exact matches (=).  Now I also want to be able to provide a more complex filtering system through the REST API that supports the ability to specific the equality match type that way they could do a != or > or LIKE, etc...  The issue is that I don't know if I am going to be able to provide this type of filtering through a normal query string.

What is the best way to provide this complex filtering through a REST API?  Is doing through a POST still considered the best way even though it is not "truly" RESTful (even though this would prevent issues of the user trying to run a long query that exceeds the URI character length limit that some browsers have)?

Comment: Running complex filters through a POST is hackish, but less hackish than using other just as error prone methods like setting a custom header. I would advise not too match the filter language too closely to your actual DB query language, as this leads to more complexity and greater chance for security holes.

Comment: I discuss this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296421/rest-complex-applications/1297275#1297275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ryanzec

> Now I also want to be able to provide a more complex filtering system
>   through the REST API that supports the ability to specific the
>   equality match type that way they could do a != or > or LIKE, etc...
>   The issue is that I don't know if I am going to be able to provide
>   this type of filtering through a normal query string.

It's not possible with simple query string(well, maybe it's possible but is very hard to encode such logic properly in query string). You need to define custom query format and use POST to submit such query. Server may respond with:

- "201 Created" status and "Location" header field indicating query resource if there was no such query before; or
- "303 See Other" and "Location" header field indicating already existing query resource.

> Is doing through a POST still considered the best way even though it
>   is not "truly" RESTful

I do not know who said this, but it's wrong. There is nothing wrong with using POST for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use forms in your collection resource responses to tell the client how to search the collections. See [my answer to REST and complex search queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110147/rest-and-complex-search-queries/13120708#13120708) for examples.