# RESTful web service in Java - 400 Bad request - Wrong method invocation?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I don't understand why this *curl* invocation gives me a 400 bad request.

```
curl -v -XGET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"match":{"first":"james"}}' http://localhost:8080/geocon/search/
```

Considered that this is the code part who should handle everything

```
@Path(Paths.SEARCH)
public class SearchService {    

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String search(@DefaultValue(NO_TYPE) @QueryParam("type") String type, String query) {
        // do interesting stuff with the query
        System.out.println(type);
        System.out.println(query);
      return //the result of the query
   }
```

Obviously, I don't see in the console the two print lines and the answer from the web service is **400 Bad request**

If I change the verb in curl and in the code (**POST** instead of **GET**), the results are OK and everything works as it should.

**Why?**

Can't I use GET passing data? If you think about it, I am not modifying stuff, I'd just receive data so GET should be the most RESTful translation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to send a body with a `GET` request, but it must **not** have any semantics; it should essentially be ignored. Not doing so violates the HTTP/1.1 specification. I suggest avoiding this practice because no one expects a request body with a `GET` request.

Now I'm not sure if the MVC framework you're using is stricter in the sense that it automatically rejects any `GET` request sent with a body, because in general a server *can* accept a `GET` request with a body, but is just supposed to ignore it.

Hence, what you're doing **is not RESTful**. The only way you can pass in data through a `GET` is through query parameters.

**UPDATE**

This is in response to your comment.

You could expose an explicit resource called `searchResult` or `search`. To create a `searchResult` or `search` resource instance, you pass in a body that is essentially a query. If you are using semantic media types (as you should for proper RESTfulness), your search-result resource could have the media type `application/vnd.myservice.search-result+json` and the query can have the media type `application/vnd.myservice.search-query+json`. Then, you can `POST` a request to `/searchResults` that has a request body that contains the complex query. The media-type of the response would be `application/vnd.myservice.search-result+json` and it can contain the search results.

So how does this play out? A search query comes in and you parse out the body and run the query. Then you should persist the results (not for ever; give it some sane TTL value). Once you have done that, you return a `303 See Other` with a `Location` header that has a link to the search results (maybe something like `/searchResults/4334`, where `4334` is the id of this particular result). The client can then access this URI to retrieve the search results. If the client requests a search result that has expired (i.e., the server cleaned it up because the TTL expired), then the server should respond with a `410 Gone`.

Also read [this](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/) for more pointers.

Comment: OK but if I want to model a research function inside my web service where queries are JSONs, POST doesn't sound really RESTful. Would you suggest to pass the whole JSON through a query parameter?

Comment: @BlacK do you really need JSON to pass filter criteria? Are there fields you need to pass other than match? Otherwise I'd just say `?first=james`.

Comment: @BlacK You could simply pass in the fields `?firstName=james`, for example. However, if you want to deal with more complex queries, take a look at some of the solutions to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110147/rest-and-complex-search-queries).

Comment: The thing is that this web service has to be able to handle Elasticsearch queries. Elasticsearch's power is that you can store your data schema-free. So if I'd use the JSON notation, I'd be able to have a good level of dynamism.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that syntax you are using has a typo.Try using the below ones for json and xml format. -XGET is wrong. it should be -X GET.

For xml
`curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://hostname/resource`

For JSON

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://hostname/resource
```

Comment: `-XGET` should work.

Comment: -XGET works for sure :)